# Resort elements by CSS (for responsive)

Tags: html, css, sorting, responsive-design

**I have 3 elements like this... :** *(and this is what i want to be, when on large-screen ✓ )*

[image: 3Elements]

**HTML :**

```
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.a {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.b {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.c {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
```

---

But problem is when on small-screen, I want to resort like **"A,C,B"** *not "A,B,C"* , and all with `width:100%;`

- Posible with **pure CSS** ? without JS/jQuery trick ? How ?
- Posible also to change HTML's pattern

---

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/oy4sc4jd/

```
@media(max-width:450px){
    .a, .b {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know all heights aren't changing you could position: absolute on large screens and change the order of your html. Other options is keep HTML as is and position: absolute on small screen. Third option is to use jQuery to reorder your html, I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @donnywals Thanks, thats problem about height as you say :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to use table-layout for small dimensions and force "C" block render at the bottom position with `caption-side` property:

```
@media(max-width:450px){
    .a, .b {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .b {
        display: table-caption;
        caption-side: bottom;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

`.container` is a wrapper element for A-B-C blocks.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oy4sc4jd/2/

Comment: Perfect !, thanks. `caption-side` is (most) cross-browser support ? (min. IE9 required)

Comment: Yes, IE8 should understand `caption-side`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a common `#wrapper` element you may use a CSS3 solution with `display: flex` defining the order of appereance of your elements: http://jsfiddle.net/njfcefqd/

CSS

```
@media(max-width:450px){

    #wrapper {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
    }

    .a, .b {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .a { order: 1; }
    .b { order: 3; }
    .c { order: 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox with the option to display column on small @media:

```
.a {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #a22020;
}
.b {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #20a260;
}
.c {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #204ba2;
}

@media(max-width:450px){

.flex{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column ;
}
  .a {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    order: 1;
    }
.b {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    order: 3;
    }
.c{
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    order: 2;
    }
}
```

or check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/oy4sc4jd/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way of doing it

```css
.hidden{display:none;}

.a {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #a22020;
}
.b {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #20a260;
}
.c {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #204ba2;
}

@media(max-width:450px){
    .a, .b {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .b{ display:none;}
    .b ~ .hidden{
           display: inline-block;
    }
}



.a,.b,.c {font-size:35px;color:#fff;text-align:center;padding-top:60px;}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
<div class="b hidden">B</div>
```